# Python error while generating code snippets with minted and Pygments in Anki

Tags: minted, python, pygments, anki

On the command line everything works fine but in in Anki I get a python error.

My computer:

```
MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012)
Processor 2 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
```

My operating system:

```
OS X El Capitan
Version 10.11 (15A284)
```

My python library

```
~ % which python
/usr/bin/python
```

My python version:

```
~ % python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

This is my Edit_LaTeX_build_process.py file (**Note:** `-shell-escape`):

```
newLaTeX = \
[
    ["/Library/TeX/texbin/latex", "-shell-escape", "-interaction=nonstopmode", "tmp.tex"],
    ["/Library/TeX/texbin/dvipng", "-D", "200", "-T", "tight", "tmp.dvi", "-o", "tmp.png"]
]

# make the changes
import anki.latex
anki.latex.latexCmds = newLaTeX
```

These are my Card options (**Note:** `\usepackage{minted}`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
\tiny
```

Successful test on command line:

test.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\special{papersize=3in,5in}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{cpp}

    #include
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        return 0;
    }

\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Shell command:

```
~ % latex -shell-escape test.tex
```

Unsuccessful test in Anki:

```
[latex]
\begin{minted}{cpp}

#include
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}

\end{minted}
[/latex]
```

Error output:

```
Error executing /Library/TeX/texbin/latex.
Generated file:   /var/folders/_q/53_csl094rqfn9rr18bn3bpw0000gn/T/anki_temp/tmp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015)  (preloaded format=latex)
\write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tmp.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 21 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-   dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-  dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifplatform/ifplatform.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/catchfile.sty)
(./tmp.w18))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty))
(./_minted-tmp/default.pygstyle)/usr/local/bin/pygmentize
(./tmp.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015basic/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))
(./_minted-tmp/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)Traceback (most recent call   last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site- packages/py2app/apptemplate/lib/site.py", line 22, in <module>
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build   tool.

See the minted package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.22 \end{minted}

(./tmp.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
No pages of output.
Transcript written on tmp.log.
```

Any help getting this to work is very much appreciated because after trying to get this to work for over a day now I ran out of ideas.

Comment: This looks like an issue with the Python installation. According to the end of the log, Python can't find `zlib`.

Comment: Yes, it seems so but the odd thing is that on the command line everything works fine (no python error whatsoever).

Comment: Have you tried running `pygmentize -V` on the command line (to get Pygments version)? If that gives an error, it might help. Also, have you tried importing `zlib` after starting Python on the command line?

Comment: I just ran `pygmentize -V` and got no error and also starting python on the command line and importing zlib went fine. Somehow I get the feeling that it is an Anki related problem.

Comment: It looks like Anki is being bundled as a standalone application with `py2app`, and that is breaking. [Possibly related/relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15612708/py2app-invalid-link-to-zlib).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. At least I know now that I can stop searching and try to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the problem is that `pygmentize` which is called by the `minted` package is a python script. When called from inside Anki.app, `pygmentize` uses the python environment inside of Anki, which is not a complete python distribution.

Anyhow, I solved this by making pygmentize a standalone executable using PyInstaller:

```
$ sudo pip install pyinstaller
```

Unfortunately the current version of pyinstaller has a problem on El Capitan ([issue tracker](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1650)) which is however relatively easy to fix. Use a text editor to replace all instances of `shutil.copy2` to `shutil.copy` in the following files:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/osx.py
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/utils.py
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyInstaller/lib/macholib/util.py
```

Now you can build the standalone `pygmentize` executable and move it in place:

```
$ cd ~
$ pyinstaller --onefile /usr/local/bin/pygmentize
$ sudo mv /usr/local/bin/pygmentize /usr/local/bin/pygmentize~
$ sudo cp dist/pygmentize /usr/local/bin/pygmentize
```

This worked for me. I hope this helps!

Stephan